# Is it possible to use the return type of a function as the type of a variable?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Let say I have this function:

```
let getData = () => {
    return {
        name: 'John',
        age: 2,
        isAsian: true
    }
}
```

How do I say (if even possible) that a variable's type is the return type of `getData`, **without** affecting it to `getData`?

For example, I'm looking for something like:

```
var data: getData
```

Of course this does not work, as the type would be the function and not the return value of the function. (**Edit**: Actually it would just give the error: `Cannot find name 'getData'`)

`var data = getData()` would work; the type of `data` would be inferred to `{name: string, age: number, isAsian: boolean}`, but this is not a solution for me.

There is a discussion here that might be related to my issue: [Obtaining the return type of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015691/obtaining-the-return-type-of-a-function)

However, it does not seem to be the solution I'm looking for. First I can't use Typescript 2.8 yet (I'm using angular and the CLI won't let me). I think that the alternative, just like the main solution of this SO question is not useful to me, because I'm looking to use the return type of my function dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of TypeScript 2.9 (sorry), you can use the `ReturnType` type:

```
let getData = () => {
    return {
        name: 'John',
        age: 2,
        isAsian: true
    }
}

let p: ReturnType<typeof getData>;
p.name; // string
```

There are workarounds you can use prior to 2.9 but they're not very good. One way is:

```
let fake = (false as any) && getData();
let p: typeof fake;
```

Comment: It's pretty cool that you can use typeof to generate the type of a variable. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

[Here is another solution for pre-2.8 compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41252607/43848). It still involves one extra function and one dummy variable, but it does not have a call to `getData()` in the code:

```
let getData = () => {
    return {
        name: 'John',
        age: 2,
        isAsian: true
    }
}


function getReturnType<R>(f: (...args: any[]) => R): { returnType: R } {
    return null!;
}

// dummy variable, used for retrieving getData return type only
let dataType = getReturnType(getData);

var data: typeof dataType.returnType; // var data: { name: string; age: number; isAsian: boolean; }
```